# Reading a CSV file into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have csv data that looks like this and I'm trying to read it into a pandas df and I've tired all sorts of combinations given the ample documentation online - I've tried things like:

```
pd.read_csv("https://www.nwrfc.noaa.gov/natural/nat_norm_text.cgi?id=TDAO3.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=0, low_memory=False)
```

and I get this error -

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 989
```

Or, like this but get an empty dataframe:

```
pd.read_csv('https://www.nwrfc.noaa.gov/natural/nat_norm_text.cgi?id=TDAO3.csv', skiprows=2, 
skipfooter=3,index_col=[0], header=None,
             engine='python', # c engine doesn't have skipfooter
             sep='delimiter')
Out[31]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

The first 10 lines of the csv file look like this:

```
# Water Supply Monthly Volumes for COLUMBIA - THE DALLES DAM (TDAO3) 
# Volumes are in KAF 
ID,Calendar Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec
TDAO3,1948,,,,,,,,,,6866.8,4307.04,4379.38
TDAO3,1949,3546.71,4615.1,8513.31,15020.45,35251.67,21985.99,11226.06,6966.73,4727.37,4406.29,5266.74,5595.91
TDAO3,1950,4353.86,5540.21,9696.27,12854.81,23359.51,39246.78,23393.23,9676.77,5729.74,6990.31,8300.03,8779.57
TDAO3,1951,8032.32,10295.98,7948.59,16144.8,36000.88,28334.09,19735.49,9308.15,6546.95,8907.1,6461.14,6425.76
TDAO3,1952,4671,6222.25,6551.62,18678.3,34866.91,27120.65,15994.18,7907.55,4810.39,3954.32,3259.29,3231.49
TDAO3,1953,7839.72,7870.96,6527.74,9474.66,23384.47,32668.32,17422.63,8655.16,5220.04,5130.46,5183.5,5915.14
TDAO3,1954,5197.51,5967.07,6718.36,10813.69,29190.37,32673.26,29624.38,13456.13,9165.78,5440.92,5732.22,4973.53
```

thank you,

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: code works for me if I use first version with `skiprows=2`

Comment: when I run second version without `sep='delimiter'` then I see some data but they different.

Comment: When I check again first version then I see `<br>` in my data - it seems it is not pure CSV but HTML displaying data. And this can make problem. maybe it needs `sep='<br>'`

Comment: yeah, i end up with a pandas of shape (0, 989) and I'm not sure what to do with that.

Comment: you should check if there is no other link to data because this link is NOT directly file but to page which convert it to HTML to display in web browser. When I open link in web browser and check source code (Ctrl+U) then I see `<pre>`, `<br>` `<title>`, `<body>`. If you don't get link directly to file then you will have to download HTML (ie. with `requests`) and create code to parse it (ie. with `lxml` or `re` for regex or even using standart string-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not link directly to file CSV but to page which displays it as HTML using tags `<pre>`, `<br>`, etc. and this makes problem.

But you can use `requests` to download it as text.

Later you can use standard `string`-functions to get text between `<pre>` and `</pre>` and replace `<br>` with `'\n'` - and you will have text with correct CSV.

And later you can use `io.StringIO` to create file in memory - to load it with `pd.read_csv()` without saving on disk.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

url = "https://www.nwrfc.noaa.gov/natural/nat_norm_text.cgi?id=TDAO3.csv"

response = requests.get(url)

start = response.text.find('<pre>') + len('<pre>')
end   = response.text.find('</pre>')

pre = response.text[start:end]

text = pre.replace('<br>', '\n')

buf = io.StringIO(text)  # file-like object in memory

df = pd.read_csv(buf, skiprows=2, low_memory=False)

print(df.to_string())
```

Result

```
      ID  Calendar Year       Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug      Sep       Oct      Nov       Dec
0   TDAO3           1948       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN   6866.80  4307.04   4379.38
1   TDAO3           1949   3546.71   4615.10   8513.31  15020.45  35251.67  21985.99  11226.06   6966.73  4727.37   4406.29  5266.74   5595.91
2   TDAO3           1950   4353.86   5540.21   9696.27  12854.81  23359.51  39246.78  23393.23   9676.77  5729.74   6990.31  8300.03   8779.57
3   TDAO3           1951   8032.32  10295.98   7948.59  16144.80  36000.88  28334.09  19735.49   9308.15  6546.95   8907.10  6461.14   6425.76
4   TDAO3           1952   4671.00   6222.25   6551.62  18678.30  34866.91  27120.65  15994.18   7907.55  4810.39   3954.32  3259.29   3231.49
5   TDAO3           1953   7839.72   7870.96   6527.74   9474.66  23384.47  32668.32  17422.63   8655.16  5220.04   5130.46  5183.50   5915.14
6   TDAO3           1954   5197.51   5967.07   6718.36  10813.69  29190.37  32673.26  29624.38  13456.13  9165.78   5440.92  5732.22   4973.53
7   TDAO3           1955   4124.26   3570.41   3843.46   7993.82  18505.47  31619.54  20408.54   8922.94  4983.31   5842.70  6982.45   9076.44
8   TDAO3           1956   8079.70   5366.62   8818.69  19754.46  40600.06  40447.34  19846.89   9726.93  5503.69   5446.20  4988.98   6006.80
9   TDAO3           1957   3940.08   4411.33   9155.00  12271.77  40111.86  27864.70  11585.75   6795.70  4613.31   4767.38  4087.55   4789.04
10  TDAO3           1958   4838.12   8246.89   7303.03  13902.66  33958.88  26239.62  12516.52   6898.78  4968.03   5198.19  6662.24   7616.43

... rest ...
```

Comment: if they would use `<table>` to display data then you could read it with `pd.read_html(url)` and it would convert all `<table>` to `DataFrame`

Comment: this is amazing- thank you very much!